# How to write text center of the area using imagemap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagemap

I used map and area attr and for styling them , i used maphighlight.js which is jquery. When i hover , it shows borders and color fillings etc.

Now i want to put text center of each areas which are determined with coordinates. When page loads , i want to see texts on center of areas "without hover" and after hover i wanna see borders ,color etc. Thanks for your helps.
Here's my code. 1)Maphilight

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.map').maphilight();
});
```

2)I tried to write text but not works properly

```
    $(function() {

    $('area').each(function(){
        var txt=$(this).data('name');
        var coor=$(this).attr('coords');
        var coorA=coor.split(',');
        var left=coorA[0];
        var top=coorA[1];

        var $span=$('<span class="map_title">'+txt+'</span>');        
        $span.css({top: top+'px', left: left+'px', position:'absolute'});
        $span.appendTo('.content');
    }) 
})
```

This is mapping

```
<div class="content">

<img src="ozak.jpg" alt="" class="map" width="2000" height="2000" border="0" usemap="#demo">
</div>
<map name="demo">
     <area  id="51" alt="D1" class ="tooltip" title="3+1 150 m² Deniz Manzaralı " href="javascript: alert('Daire 5127 Satılmıştır!')" coords="588,271,816,369" shape="rect" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"000000","strokeWidth":5,"fillColor":"F72E06","fillOpacity":0.7}' data-name="Daire1">
    <area  alt="" title="" href="javascript: alert('Daire 5287 Satılıktır!')" coords="1251,278,1374,367" shape="rect" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"000000","strokeWidth":5,"fillColor":"00BD06","fillOpacity":0.7}' data-name="Daire2">
  <area alt="" title="" href="javascript: alert('Daire 8692 Satılmıştır!')" coords="600,469,807,554" shape="rect" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"000000","strokeWidth":5,"fillColor":"F72E06","fillOpacity":0.7}' data-name="Daire3">


</map>
```

CSS

```
#map {
    position:relative
}
.map_title {
    position:absolute;    
}
```

Comment: So, your texts like "Daire1", "Daire3", etc are already appearing and you are getting border/color on hover. So do you just want to align them center?

Comment: @MayankPatel Yes exactly. Texts are appearing on the left corner but i couldn't align them center. text-align:center didn't worked for me.

Comment: Kindly check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that I have used my own image.

How `coords="588,271,816,369"` works:

- Here it is x1,y1,x2,y2 where x1,y1 is for top-left corner of area and x2,y2 is bottom-right corner.
- Second thing is that you need to parse these cordinates to integer to calculate top/left attribute of your text.
- Now, you can calculate left attribute by using this formula. `parseInt(coorA[0])+((parseInt(coorA[2])-parseInt(coorA[0]))/2)`. And same for top

Please note, here the point I calculated is the exact center of your `rect` but it is appearing sligh the right side as it is starting from the exact center point. You can apply some more mathematics to get it exactly center aligned.

**EDIT**

You can calculate the width of your span and get its width. After that, divide by 2 will give you the pixes you need subtract to get your labels accurately in the center. Here, I assume some pixels are being utilized in the border so I have back 9 pixels to it as an adjustment. It can be removed if you feel it's working fine.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.map').maphilight();
    $('area').each(function(){
        var txt=$(this).data('name');
        var coor=$(this).attr('coords');
        var coorA=coor.split(',');
        
        var left=parseInt(coorA[0])+((parseInt(coorA[2])-parseInt(coorA[0]))/2);
        var top=parseInt(coorA[1])+((parseInt(coorA[3])-parseInt(coorA[1]))/2)
        
        var $span=$('<span class="map_title">'+txt+'</span>');        
        $span.css({top: top+'px', left: left+'px', position:'absolute'});        
        $span.appendTo('.content');
        $span.css({left:(left-Math.ceil($span.width()/2)+9)+'px'})
        
    }) 
});
```

```css
#map {
    position:relative
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/maphilight/1.4.0/jquery.maphilight.min.js" integrity="sha256-nUK4JHJVwdj7H1SYkkMcuE2unpjH5vYOe3mGEVu/69Q=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="content">

<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/372/200/300.jpg" alt="" class="map" width="2000" height="2000" border="0" usemap="#demo">
</div>
<map name="demo">
     <area  id="51" alt="D1" class ="tooltip" title="3+1 150 m² Deniz Manzaralı " href="javascript: alert('Daire 5127 Satılmıştır!')" coords="588,271,816,369" shape="rect" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"000000","strokeWidth":5,"fillColor":"F72E06","fillOpacity":0.7}' data-name="Daire1">
    <area  alt="" title="" href="javascript: alert('Daire 5287 Satılıktır!')" coords="1251,278,1374,367" shape="rect" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"000000","strokeWidth":5,"fillColor":"00BD06","fillOpacity":0.7}' data-name="Daire2">
  <area alt="" title="" href="javascript: alert('Daire 8692 Satılmıştır!')" coords="600,469,807,554" shape="rect" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"000000","strokeWidth":5,"fillColor":"F72E06","fillOpacity":0.7}' data-name="Daire3">


</map>
```